# Object references issue. How is the child component changing the state of its parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

## **Explanation**

I expect props to be immutable and a child component unable to change its parent component's state directly (other than if there is a callback). However in the below code it seems that the parent state is getting changed by a function that is in the child component without a callback.

The parent component is as below and retrieves data from an API (I have just put in a test data constant for this question, see test data below).

```js
const  TestParentComponent = () => {
    const [testData, setTestData] = useState(TEST_DATA)
        return (
            <TestChildComponent
                testData={testData}
            />
        )
}
```

The child component is as below and simply will display the data but before display will remove duplicates in a `hits` array in the `testData` object.

```js
const TestChildComponent = ({ testData }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        loadStructure()
    }, [testData])

    const removeDuplicateRawText = queryObject => {
        let newQueryObject = queryObject

        const rawTextAsUniqueKeyMap =
            new Map(newQueryObject.index_result.hits.hits.map(hit =>
                [hit._source.raw_text, hit]
            ))

        const dedepulicatedQueryResult = Array.from(rawTextAsUniqueKeyMap.values())
        newQueryObject.index_result.hits.hits = dedepulicatedQueryResult

        return newQueryObject
    }

    const loadStructure = () => {
        if (testData) {
            return removeDuplicateRawText(testData).index_result.hits.hits
        } else {
            return
        }
    }

    return <></>
}
```

## **Question**

Upon examining the state of the parent component and the props of the child component with react tools, you will see that the `testData.index_result.hits.hits` array should be a length of 6 in both. However, they have both been transformed to a length of 2.

I would expect the state of the parent component and props received into the child component to remain static.

## **Full code**

The full code including the test data is as below.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TEST_DATA =  {
    "index_result": {
        "took": 51,
        "timed_out": false,
        "_shards": {
            "total": 1,
            "successful": 1,
            "skipped": 0,
            "failed": 0
        },
        "hits": {
            "total": {
                "value": 6,
                "relation": "eq"
            },
            "max_score": 1.1909032,
            "hits": [
                {
                    "_index": "22",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "Threaded+email%281%29.eml",
                    "_score": 1.1909032,
                    "_source": {
                        "file_name": "Threaded email(1).eml",
                        "datasource_id": 22,
                        "object_id": "Threaded email.eml",
                        "created_date": null,
                        "modified_date": "2021-03-13T13:23:11.000Z",
                        "accessed_date": null,
                        "mime_type": "message/rfc822",
                        "indexed_date": "2021-03-13T13:25:42.520Z",
                        "sha_256_hash": "d4f64da4437c2a0744610395420e759215eb646e20986e2068b5e75696fa1607",
                        "file_size": 12040,
                        "doc_lang": "en",
                        "is_processed": true,
                        "text_extraction_status": "SUCCESS",
                        "tags": [],
                        "manually_removed_tags": [],
                        "raw_text": "foo bar"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_index": "22",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "Threaded+email%285%29.eml",
                    "_score": 1.1909032,
                    "_source": {
                        "file_name": "Threaded email(5).eml",
                        "datasource_id": 22,
                        "object_id": "Threaded email(5).eml",
                        "created_date": null,
                        "modified_date": "2021-03-13T13:23:11.000Z",
                        "accessed_date": null,
                        "mime_type": "message/rfc822",
                        "indexed_date": "2021-03-13T13:25:43.709Z",
                        "sha_256_hash": "4570da7fd2d2d4fa99052662787b88bb7ce83abc850a81152e07ebc8e578f7af",
                        "file_size": 8823,
                        "doc_lang": "en",
                        "is_processed": true,
                        "text_extraction_status": "SUCCESS",
                        "tags": [],
                        "manually_removed_tags": [],
                        "raw_text": "foo bar"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_index": "22",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "Threaded+email%284%29.eml",
                    "_score": 1.1244311,
                    "_source": {
                        "file_name": "Threaded email(4).eml",
                        "datasource_id": 22,
                        "object_id": "Threaded email(4).eml",
                        "created_date": null,
                        "modified_date": "2021-03-13T13:23:11.000Z",
                        "accessed_date": null,
                        "mime_type": "message/rfc822",
                        "indexed_date": "2021-03-13T13:25:43.845Z",
                        "sha_256_hash": "ce637ec390a03ce9bbd0df96f510faad906e2f9ce1ecdb08f7998b9ea2b12879",
                        "file_size": 18158,
                        "doc_lang": "en",
                        "is_processed": true,
                        "text_extraction_status": "SUCCESS",
                        "tags": [],
                        "manually_removed_tags": [],
                        "raw_text": "bar foo"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_index": "22",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "Threaded+email.eml",
                    "_score": 1.1244311,
                    "_source": {
                        "file_name": "Threaded email.eml",
                        "datasource_id": 22,
                        "object_id": "Threaded email.eml",
                        "created_date": null,
                        "modified_date": "2021-03-13T13:23:11.000Z",
                        "accessed_date": null,
                        "mime_type": "message/rfc822",
                        "indexed_date": "2021-03-13T13:25:43.897Z",
                        "sha_256_hash": "90cc29320ad94973ab6182bdbd7c56b2ffc006c5c98b642cafd0fed7f8614dee",
                        "file_size": 15010,
                        "doc_lang": "en",
                        "is_processed": true,
                        "text_extraction_status": "SUCCESS",
                        "tags": [],
                        "manually_removed_tags": [],
                        "raw_text": "bar foo"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_index": "22",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "Threaded+email%282%29.eml",
                    "_score": 0.6855098,
                    "_source": {
                        "file_name": "Threaded email(2).eml",
                        "datasource_id": 22,
                        "object_id": "Threaded email(2).eml",
                        "created_date": null,
                        "modified_date": "2021-03-13T13:23:11.000Z",
                        "accessed_date": null,
                        "mime_type": "message/rfc822",
                        "indexed_date": "2021-03-13T13:25:42.737Z",
                        "sha_256_hash": "820e7767d7334599d7cf260e33428acb7e7a29975d5a44f959507a3898a6e232",
                        "file_size": 6959,
                        "doc_lang": "en",
                        "is_processed": true,
                        "text_extraction_status": "SUCCESS",
                        "tags": [],
                        "manually_removed_tags": [],
                        "raw_text": "foo bar"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_index": "22",
                    "_type": "_doc",
                    "_id": "Threaded+email%286%29.eml",
                    "_score": 0.6855098,
                    "_source": {
                        "file_name": "Threaded email(6).eml",
                        "datasource_id": 22,
                        "object_id": "Threaded email(6).eml",
                        "created_date": null,
                        "modified_date": "2021-03-13T13:23:11.000Z",
                        "accessed_date": null,
                        "mime_type": "message/rfc822",
                        "indexed_date": "2021-03-13T13:25:43.640Z",
                        "sha_256_hash": "c1640b17751afab44cc54a033adf360c9bcc2b06f0ba4e6c5599290dacd9b52f",
                        "file_size": 11172,
                        "doc_lang": "en",
                        "is_processed": true,
                        "text_extraction_status": "SUCCESS",
                        "tags": [],
                        "manually_removed_tags": [],
                        "raw_text": "bar foo"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

const TestChildComponent = ({ testData }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        loadStructure()
    }, [testData])

    const removeDuplicateRawText = queryObject => {
        let newQueryObject = queryObject

        const rawTextAsUniqueKeyMap =
            new Map(newQueryObject.index_result.hits.hits.map(hit =>
                [hit._source.raw_text, hit]
            ))

        const dedepulicatedQueryResult = Array.from(rawTextAsUniqueKeyMap.values())
        newQueryObject.index_result.hits.hits = dedepulicatedQueryResult

        return newQueryObject
    }

    const loadStructure = () => {
        if (testData) {
            return removeDuplicateRawText(testData).index_result.hits.hits
        } else {
            return
        }
    }

    return <></>
}

const  TestParentComponent = () => {
    const [testData, setTestData] = useState(TEST_DATA)
        return (
            <TestChildComponent
                testData={testData}
            />
        )
}

export default TestParentComponent
```

## **Sandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-snyder-sj4hb?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be a problem of object references. In JavaScript, objects are a reference type

You can solve this by cloning the passed in data in child component.

This is why you always see people using `{...state}` when dealing with React state. It essentially creates a copy of `state`. In this case you need a copy of `testData` or a object within it for the child to modify

Comment: Yep,  "newQueryObject.index_result.hits.hits = dedepulicatedQueryResult"  Object is modified here.

Comment: Thanks both. I did go down the object references route for a while, but doesn't `let newQueryObject = queryObject` in the child component `removeDuplicateRawText` function solve the object references issue since I'm not modifying the prop directly but rather a copy of it?

Comment: `let newQueryObject = queryObject` here `newQueryObject` is just a direct reference to `queryObject`, it's not a copy of it. If you do `let newQueryObject = {...queryObject}` or traditional `Object.assign`, `_.clone()` etc then it's a copy

Comment: Thanks again TJ. I tried both deconstructing `queryObject` as above and also using `Object.assign` but it is still mutating the parent state component. I also tried to declare a state object in the parent object and then deconstruct it as well...

Comment: Could you create a https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new  ?

Comment: Yes sure. Will update the issue above. Thanks again!